# Retry javascript function few times before returning me an error

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript function as shown below

```
var url = 'test'

var pingStatus = false


createjob(url,  function(err, client){
        client.ImportData(obj, function(err, result) {
            if(result.Import[0] ==='1')
            {
                pingStatus = true
                console.log("Worked")
            }
            else
            {  
                pingStatus = false
                console.log("Didnt Work")
            }
        });
});
```

I want to be able to try creating the job 3 times and if it fails 3 times, I want to run some other function that does something else.

I have tried a for loop and tried to break out of the for loop but was getting an error saying the break was illegal. (the if statement is in a callback function)

Could someone point me in the right direction to acheive this.

I also tried checking with global variable 'pingSatus' but it does not work as the code executes before the pingStatus variable is set in the if statements

Comment: recursion is one search term - also, look into how to work with asynchronous code

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know what your job exactly do, I'll propose something like that:

```js
var url = 'test'

var pingStatus = false

var yourJob = {
 iteration: 0,
 /*yourJobLogic: function(url,  function(err, client){
        client.ImportData(obj, function(err, result) {
            if(result.Import[0] ==='1')
            {
                pingStatus = true
                console.log("Worked")
            }
            else
            {  
                pingStatus = false
                console.log("Didnt Work")
            }
        });
 },*/
 yourJobLogic: function(n){
  this.iteration++;
  console.log("Trying to do the job for the " + this.iteration + " time...");
  var yourConditionToPass = (n===123);
  if(this.iteration>=3){
   console.error("We tried 3 times and your job doesn't work, exit!");
   throw "Your number can(t be used....";
  }else{
   if(yourConditionToPass){
    console.info("Your job is done.");
    return true;
   }
   this.yourJobLogic(n);
  }
 },
 doJob: function(n){
        this.iteration = 0;
  this.yourJobLogic(n);
 }
};

var result = yourJob.doJob(123);
console.log(result);
//outputs: 
// Trying to do the job for the 1 time...
// Your job is done.

var result = yourJob.doJob(789);
/* outputs:
Trying to do the job for the 1 time...
Trying to do the job for the 2 time...
Trying to do the job for the 3 time...
We tried 3 times and your job doesn't work, exit!Uncaught Your number can(t be used...
*/
```

All you need to do is to change **yourJobLogic** and **yourConditionToPass**.

Does this help you?

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = 'test'

var pingStatus = false

var tryTimes = 0;

createjob(url,  function(err, client){
        client.ImportData(obj, function(err, result) {
            if(result.Import[0] ==='1')
            {
                pingStatus = true;
                tryTimes = 0;
                console.log("Worked");
            }
            else
            {  
                pingStatus = false;
                console.log("Didnt Work");
                tryTimes += 1;
                arguments.callee(err, result);
                if(tryTimes === 3){
                    tryTimes = 0;
                    YOURFUNCTIONTORUN();
                }
            }
        });
});
```